# Google maps expand limitation of rectangle boundary

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Please find the google mapsApi documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#editable 
Please zoomout to world view and then expand the region selection towards right in single attempt. At some point you could observe that the selection became unstable and it selects entirely different section of the world.

By default the rectangle selection tool seems to look for shortest possible path to complete the shape.  This creates a strange behavior when attempting to draw a very very large region.

1. I wanted to click and drag a very large region that covered a large geography.  I was dragging West to East.  Once the size of the object was very large, the selection reserved and was covering a completely different section of the world.
2. I attempt to expand a boundary to include the entire world.  When the boundary goes far enough, again the region appears to be the minimal/smaller area.

Expected behavior was the selector to continue expanding in the direction the user intends.  In this case I would expect the selector to continue its west to east expansion.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#editable

```
var bounds = {north: 44.599, south: 44.490, east: -78.443, west: -78.649 }; // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true. var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({bounds: bounds, editable: true});
```

[Please tries to expands rectangle to further right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svUAD.png)

Is there a solution to resolve the scenario mentioned?

Please let me know if further details required.

Comment: Your question is too broad, unclear, and we don't know what you have tried and where/how it fails, because you didn't post any code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve and the issue(s) you are facing.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Please find the google mapsApi documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#editable Please tries to zoomout to world view and then expand the region selection towords right in single attempt. At some point you could observe that the selection became unstable and it selects entirely different section of the world.

Comment: It expands in the opposite direction, not *a completely different section of the world*. This is logical... it will use the shortest path from one side of the shape to the other, around the globe. Don't forget it's a representation of a sphere...

Comment: Thanks, we can still select the entire region if we selects the region in multiple attempts. In my requirement I need to select entire region in single attempt and it looks like it 's impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, when you drag it "too far", the rectangle left and right coordinates (longitude) get inverted.

In other words, if you drag it too far to the right, right will become left and left will be where you dragged the right side to. And the opposite in the other direction. So by comparing where *was* the left with where *is* the right or vice-versa, you can detect if your rectangle left and right got inverted and invert it again... This way you can achieve what you want.

And of course if you drag the right side further to the right than where the left was (or the other way around), it will reset, as you can't have a rectangle overlapping itself around the globe.

The UI can be a bit confusing though, as you can see the rectangle lines get inverted but you can't do much about that.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 2,
    zoomControl: false
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // Set origin bounds
  var originBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-20, -100),
    new google.maps.LatLng(20, 20)
  );

  // Get left/right coords
  var left = originBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var right = originBounds.getNorthEast().lng();

  // Create editable rectangle
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: originBounds,
    fillColor: 'white',
    fillOpacity: .5,
    editable: true,
    map: map
  });

  // Check for rectangle bounds changed
  google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'bounds_changed', function() {

    // Get currents bounds and left/right coords
    var newBounds = rectangle.getBounds();
    var newLeft = newBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var newRight = newBounds.getNorthEast().lng();

    if ((newRight === left) || (newLeft === right)) {

      // User dragged "too far" left or right and rectangle got inverted
      // Invert left and right coordinates
      rectangle.setBounds(invertBounds(newBounds));
    }

    // Reset current left and right
    left = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    right = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
  });
}

function invertBounds(bounds) {

  // Invert the rectangle bounds
  var invertedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), bounds.getNorthEast().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng())
  );

  return invertedBounds;
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```